# Restful web service in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest

I am using Restful web service in eclipse. Few days ago it is running smoothly. But today, something goes wrong. Web services are running properly but when I modified something on web service program it does not reflect after invoking the web service. I have noticed earlier that whenever I changed small code in my program the server starts automatically and it reflects on the fly. 
Now my web service starts but seems like it runs from cache. Whatever I modified in the program it does not show in output. I have restart (stop & start) the server and even restart the eclipse but nothing changes. It gives always previous results. for example

```
@Path("/todo")
public class TodoResource {
  // This method is called if XMLis request
 @GET
//@Path("/text")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Todo getXML() {
Todo todo = new Todo();
todo.setSummary("testing web service");
todo.setDescription("This is my first todo using restful");
return todo;
}
```

when I run this web service, it gives output as

```
testing web service
This is my first todo using restful
```

When I modified somthing like  (just segement of code 4444 is added)
    todo.setSummary("testing web service 4444");

it does not display 4444, instead it show older output 
    testing web service
    This is my first todo using restful

Its really strange and I do not know what goes wrong. 
Any helps or suggestions are appreciated.

Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Thanks in advance

Shrestha

Comment: Is it using Tomcat managed from Eclipse?

Comment: Try to clear out browser cache.

Comment: @David, yes, it is using Tomcat from Eclipse.

Comment: @Aman, browswer is cleared and also I am running from command line using "curl".

Answer (score 1):

- Stop the Tomcat server from Eclipse (via the Servers view)
- Check to make sure you have no compile errors in your code
- Right click on the Tomcat server in Eclipse and select the menu item Clean...
- Start the Tomcat server again from Eclipse

Comment: did as you said,but no success.

Comment: Last thing I would recommend trying is put a breakpoint in your getXML() method. And verify the values in the ToDo object just before returning it.

Comment: No any success yet. It seems that web service is running from different source though there is only one web service running. If I change the path "todo" (from above example) to "todo2" and try to access with http://localhost:8080/..../todo2 it says service not found and still http://localhost:8080/..../todo works while I have modified it to todo2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; managed to resolved it by cleaning the project:

> Project > Clean ...

Stopping, starting/cleaning the server didn't do a thing for me.